# DiskInventor & OmniDiskSweeper shows different size as Disk Utility

Tags: macos, time-machine, disk-utility

I am running 10.9.4 and have a 120 GB hard drive. Disk Inventory X shows only 51.9 GB of data, but About this Mac and Disk utility show less than 10 GB free space.

I tried these items:

- Timemachine is off
- sudo tmutil disablelocal
- ran OmniDiskSweeper

Can you please help me understand the discrepancy in sizing?

[image: Disk Inventory X]

[image: About this Mac...]

[image: Disk Utility]

Comment: Which numbers are you comparing between the two screen shots? Which number are you looking for as being correct?

Comment: @patrix IMHO he want compare the `51.9` used place from the 1st tool, (the funny colored thing) and the `Belegt (Used): 111.51` from the Disk Utility.

Comment: this is correct jm666. i have a 128GB SSD HDD and only 51.9 are shown. and i even run out of space and dont know how to handle the problem

Comment: Could you check something please? Click the Apple menu in the top-left corner of the screen and choose "About this Mac...". Open the Storage tab and tell us how much it says is being used for "Backups".

Comment: http://pix.defcon5.biz/files/15525656181204582729.png "sonstige" is in english "other"...

Comment: Can you move those images to something like [Imgur](http://imgur.com)? The site you've linked is throwing errors indicating that hotlinking is not allowed.

Comment: 64.67GB of "Other". Backup is 0KB so the space isn't taken with local Time Machine backups. Are there a large number of files in your Trash folder or possibly the Trash folder of another account?

Comment: @MikeyT.K. http://i.imgur.com/tf7jlA0.png

Comment: @AlistairMcMillan i have no other accounts there wich have data. my wife's paperbin is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The biggest issue here is that you need to run your analysis tools as root. If you don't do this, you'll only see the files that your account has access to, and so you won't see everything that is taking up space.

I like GrandPerspective personally. If it's in your Applications folder, the command to run it as root looks like this:

```
sudo /Applications/GrandPerspective.app/Contents/MacOS/GrandPerspective
```

Comment: i just downloaded grandperspective and im trying this as admin

Comment: You found the source of the discrepancy?